# Multiple search and return multiple values for same matches

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MultipleSearch()
Dim aNum(), aTabl(), aRes()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
With Worksheets("List1") 
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aTabl = .Range("A1:G" & i).Value 
End With

With Worksheets("List2") 
    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 
    aNum = .Range("D1:D" & i).Value 
    ReDim aRes(1 To i + 3, 1 To 1) 
    aRes(1, 1) = .Range("K1").Value 
End With

For i = 2 To UBound(aNum) 
    n = i 
    For k = 2 To UBound(aTabl) 
        If aTabl(k, 1) <> Empty Then 
            If aNum(i, 1) = aTabl(k, 1) Then
                aRes(n, 1) = aTabl(k, 7): n = n + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next k
Next i

Worksheets("List2").Range("K1").Resize(UBound(aRes), 1).Value = aRes
End Sub
```

Hi. I have a code that lookup value on Picture 1 in 4.column and value on Picture 2 in 1.column and when it matches it returns value from Picture 2. from 8.column as you see.
I need to make a change. I need to return value from 8.column in other way.

When its the first match of 26054112 i need to return the first number from 8.column - -10629425,25
When its second match of 26054112 i need to return the second number - -1549761,31
And so on...

[image]

[image]

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797678/using-find-in-a-recursive-function#37815689) for a recursive Find function.

Comment: Have you tried using 'VlookUp' in a loop?

Comment: i had a look, but i still dont understand how i can implement this in my code.

Comment: @VladStepanov - You keep searching for the values for as many times as they appear and then you can pull the needed value. (There's also a bulit-in check against the first value found so you don't have an endless loop). [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) actually will be more helpful to you in understanding concept.